# Округление числа Builder C++

Tags: c++builder

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с следующей проблемой:
Есть некая написанная программа на C++ Builder 6 выполняющая серверную роль, опрашивает pci модули и производит нужный расчет, затем записывает данные в бин. файл и бд, далее клиент может просмотреть нужную информацию, но дело в том что при опросе модуля гуляет тысячная которая участвует в расчете, и я хочу эту тысячную округлять, диапазон разброса не большой +-1 тыс. Решил использовать фун-цию RoundTo но она мне не помогла тысячная как гуляла так и гуляет. Тогда решил посмотреть что происходит, создал тестовый пример:

```
float t,a = 1.001,Hl,Hh;
 t=a;
 t=RoundTo(t, -2);
 Hl=t-(t*.15); Hh=t+(t*.15);
Chart1->LeftAxis->SetMinMax(Hl,Hh);
Label1->Caption = Hl;
```

При значении 1.001 не особо заметно, но если например попадают сл. данные 1,151 и тогда можно заметить 1,977499961853027 - меня этот ответ не устраивает и если пересчитать на калькуляторе то мы получим число 0,97835 что также меня не устраивает, потому как я уже говорил выше тысячная гуляет на +-1 и должно быть вместо 1,151 - 1,150 а при 1,150 значения равны 0,9775 что мне и нужно. Перечитав много информации я понял что проблема с типами а именно когда я заменил тип с float на double мои данные стали отображаться так как мне нужно, но я не хочу менять тип, как реализовать тот же результат но с типом float ?

Comment: Всё ещё актуально, очень нужна ваша помощь, помогите разобраться пожалуйста, спасибо.